# ES6 imports: can we make this fail? import React, {BadKey} from "react";

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'd like my imports to be more fail-fast. I want my build process to fail if someone tries to import something that does not exist.

For default imports it seems to work fine, as the following will fail:

```
import Something from "doesNotExist";
```

But if I import an attribute of an existing module, it does not fail:

```
import React, {BadKey} from "react";
```

How can I make it fail by default?

I'm using Webpack / Babel5 / NPM 2.14

Comment: I don't think you can. `BadKey` will be undefined. BTW, technically speaking, this is not called an "attribute", it's called a "named export".

Comment: If you are willing to use eslint, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import .

Comment: thanks @FelixKling good to know. I am willing to use it as I guess I can only enable this specific rule so it's not very intrusive right?

Comment: That should be possible, yes.

Comment: FWIW, the plugin can only fail modules that export ES6 syntax in the package. so it works best with either only application code, or modules that specify Rollup's `jsnext:main`, like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/package.json#L6) does.

Answer (score 1):

Use a strongly-typed language like Typescript, which can error in this condition. We actually moved to eliminate all our default exports and imports, because the name checking available for `import { Thing }` is super helpful.

Comment: That's a solution for sure :D Does Flow also solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Webpack, [eslint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-loader) is one way to integrate with ESLint as part of your build process.

Webpack can be a little cryptic with errors during module builds, though, so take note of the `NoErrorsPlugin` at the bottom of the README.

Also, consider using Webpack's `bail` flag (set to `true`) to abandon building as soon as module errors are encountered. IIRC the default Webpack behavior just omits the error-ing module from the emitted bundle with a note in the console, which will result in a runtime error anyway (module missing).